# What does split('\000') do in this python code?

Tags: python, winapi, split

```
drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
drives = drives.split('\000')[:-1]
```

Above is a piece of code from a project I was assigned to. After the first line is executed, the drives variable is the following:

```
C:\D:\
```

After the second line is executed, it turns into this:

```
['C:\\', 'D:\\']
```

But what does '\000' mean exactly? I've never seen that before.

Comment: The win32api.GetLogicalDrivesStrings returns a terminator-embedded string, ending with a double-terminator (nullchar). Each drive string in the returned data is separated by a single terminator (nullchar). The string ends with a double-terminator. The split you're showing splits on the terminator (nullchar), to form the individual drive strings and populate the sequence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'\000' is an octal sequence. The intention of the code is obviously to split on NULL.

If the code works as stated in the question then the actual value returned from *GetLogicalDriveStrings()* is:

```
"C:\\\000D:\\\000"
```

Of course, if you *print()* that, what you'll see is:

```
C:\D:\
```

Answer (score 2):

`win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings` returns a string of the drives separated by the Null character, code point 0. It can be represented in a string literal with `\x00` (hex) or `\000` (octal). There is no character/glyph when you print it to your console.

Also, it's not to be confused with the character of the number `0` which is code point 48 (base 10) or 0x30 (hex).

`repr` returns the *representation* of the string.

`ord` returns the Unicode code point of a character.

```py
import win32api

drives = win32api.GetLogicalDriveStrings()
print(repr(drives))
for char in drives:
    print(ord(char), char)
```

Output:

```
'C:\\\x00D:\\\x00'
67 C
58 :
92 \
0 
68 D
58 :
92 \
0
```

See:

- https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#ord